# error : The method setString(int, String) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (int, Object)

Tags: java

I have below class file. If I try to insert values from Vector to database, then it will display below error. I want to use Vector in this case and looking how to resolve this issue.

```
error : The method setString(int, String) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (int, Object)
```

below is the class code:

```
public class ReadExcelFile {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

                String fileName = "C:\\excelFile.xls";
                Vector dataHolder = ReadCSV(fileName);
                printCellDataToConsole(dataHolder);
        }

        public static Vector ReadCSV(String fileName) {
                Vector cellVectorHolder = new Vector();

                try {
                        FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(fileName);

                        POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);

                        HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);

                        HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);

                        Iterator rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();

                        while (rowIter.hasNext()) {
                                HSSFRow myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
                                Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
                                Vector cellStoreVector = new Vector();
                                while (cellIter.hasNext()) {
                                        HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                                        cellStoreVector.addElement(myCell);
                                }
                                cellVectorHolder.addElement(cellStoreVector);
                        }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return cellVectorHolder;
        }

        public static void printCellDataToConsole(Vector dataHolder) {

                for (int i = 0; i < dataHolder.size(); i++) {
                        Vector cellStoreVector = (Vector) dataHolder.elementAt(i);
                     //   System.out.println(cellStoreVector);
                        for (int j = 0; j < cellStoreVector.size(); j++) {
                              HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellStoreVector.elementAt(j);
                              String stringCellValue = myCell.toString();
                              System.out.print(stringCellValue + "\t\t");
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                }
        }


}
```

//below is the database query

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO table_name(EMP_ID,FNAME, LNAME, CATEGORY, DEPARTMENT, Title, REASON, Manager, sDate, eDate, ID) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement pst1 = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst1.setString(1, cellStoreVector.get(0));
pst1.setString(2, cellStoreVector.get(1));
pst1.setString(3, cellStoreVector.get(2));
pst1.setString(4, cellStoreVector.get(3));
pst1.setString(5, cellStoreVector.get(4));
pst1.setString(6, cellStoreVector.get(5));
pst1.setString(7, cellStoreVector.get(6));
pst1.setString(8, cellStoreVector.get(7));
pst1.setString(9, cellStoreVector.get(8));
pst1.setString(10, cellStoreVector.get(9));
pst1.setString(11, "555");  //Hardcoded for testing. 
pst1.execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Vector` is defined to hold `Objects`.

The `Vector#get` will return an `Object`.

The `PreparedStatement#setString` method is expecting a `String`, this is a simple type mismatch issue.

You can declare you `Vector` so that it only contains `String`...

```
Vector<String> myVector = new Vector<String>(25);
```

...But I don't think you can from your example...

You can cast the value in the `Vector` to a `String`

```
pst1.setString(1, (String)cellStoreVector.get(0));
```

But this is dangerous as you won't find out that the `Vector` doesn't contain a `String` element until run-time

Or you can let the `PreparedStatement` handle it...

```
pst1.setObject(1, cellStoreVector.get(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `cellStoreVector` contains instances of `HSSFCell`. But since your using a non-generic collection, when you retrieve elements you get them as `Object`, which is why the compiler is complaining, because an `String` is expected instead.

As the cells can be of different types, how you should handle it really depends what types cells they are.

For example if all cells were for string data then there is a method which returns the value in the cell as a `String`.

[`HSSFCell#getStringCellValue`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html#getStringCellValue%28%29)

> get the value of the cell as a string - for numeric cells we throw an exception. For blank cells we return an empty string. For formulaCells that are not string Formulas, we throw an exception

So if they were all string cells, I think this is what you could do

```
pst1.setString(1, ((HSSFCell) cellStoreVector.get(0)).getStringCellValue());
```

Cast the object you get from the vector to `HSSFCell` and then get the value as `String`.

But, that's just an idea, you will have make sure what you are getting. Also, when dealing with collections it's always good use the generic versions for type safety.

Comment: I learned the exact concept from your description. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is an elementary programming error and the error message is self-explanatory. The second argument to that method is a String, not an Object. So you have to cast it to a String, if it really is a String, which it isn't in this case. You need to check your datatypes. You should be using Generics for the cellStoreVector to make this more clear and more typesafe.